# Data is repeating in arraylist inside array list in for loop Recylerview Koltin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, arraylist

I am trying to achieve expandable recylerveiew in koltin:
i tried with the below code :

```
val DataItems = arrayListOf<faqBody>()
val ChildDataItems = arrayListOf<childItem>()
var ParentDataItem: faqBody
var ChildDataItem: childItem

for (item in 0..5) {
    ParentDataItem = faqBody()
    ParentDataItem.menuText = item.toString()
    for (item1 in 0..2) {
        ChildDataItem = childItem()
        ChildDataItem.menuText = item1.toString()
        ChildDataItems .add(ChildDataItem)
        ParentDataItem.childItem = childlist
    }
    DataItems .add(ParentDataItem)
```

While trying above code, i am getting repeated data of child item in parent item
if child item is 2
parent item is 2
parent is sets fine but child item is repeating 2 times as bcoz of parent.

Can any one help to get rid of the above.
Please find the image for your reference.

[image]

Comment: I posted an answer for your question, did it help you?

Comment: it works thanks, but can you check the below comments i am facing another issue :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ChildDataItems` is out of loop's scope. New elements are added for first parent item 2 times, but then, the list remains the same, and new elements are added to the list, while the other 2 is already in there. 
Therefore, your third parent item ends up with the list of 6 childs!

Declare your list of Childs in loop's scope, not outer one

```
val DataItems = arrayListOf<faqBody>()
var ParentDataItem: faqBody
var ChildDataItem: childItem

for (item in 0..5) {
    ParentDataItem = faqBody()
    ParentDataItem.menuText = item.toString()

    val ChildDataItems = arrayListOf<childItem>() // a new list will be created for each parent       

    for (item1 in 0..2) {
        ChildDataItem = childItem()
        ChildDataItem.menuText = item1.toString()
        ChildDataItems .add(ChildDataItem)
        ParentDataItem.childItem = childlist
    }
    DataItems .add(ParentDataItem)
}
```

*P.S. names of your variables should start with lower case letters, and names of classes/interfaces should start with upper case letters. This code-style is usually followed in modern Java/Kotlin production*

Comment: Awesome , thanks man...
But then i put "ParentDataItem = faqBody()" in if else condition , not able to find the same in for (item1 in 0..2) {
        ChildDataItem = childItem()
        ChildDataItem.menuText = item1.toString()
        ChildDataItems .add(ChildDataItem)
        ParentDataItem.childItem = childlist
    }

Comment: If possible you can help me in this also :)

Comment: @SachinGupta I need to see the full code. You can edit your question, write something like "UPD1" and post your new code below it and explain which kind of error/unexpected behavior you get.

Comment: I have updated the code , please let me know if you want any other thing

Comment: Bro , i found it my mistake , thanks for your quick response :)

Comment: @SachinGupta you are welcome. If your question is closed, you can accept my answer :)